# How to know Number of turns

Tags: coil, homework

In closed magnetic circuit, How many **turns** are when a conductor winded around a square mild steel core with permeability (Ur=2410)?

The outer length is 20 cm and inner length is 16 cm. The current measured is 1.482 A. Length of the coil is 10 cm

Any Hint where to begin?
[image]

Comment: The number of turns determines the inductance L of the coil, which affects the current flowing through it. But I think there is missing some information. What is the voltage applied?

Comment: The volt is not given.

Comment: I edited the question and assumed you mean you mean 1.482 A, not 1482 A (where 1,482 is the US way of writing).

Comment: I did write 1,482 A

Comment: there isn't enough information to solve this... What guage wire. What inductance, what frequency AC, what voltage (Vs...) ... there is no depth so the window of the core is unknown.

Comment: This is a homework question and I have been struggling for days to find the answer but I did not. I tried most formula in the book but none can be used. either missing the voltage or the cross section and so on.

Comment: If you assume the magnetic flux density for your mild steel core is 1T.    Then we can solve for H = 33.02 A/m and N = (H *Le)/I = (33.02A/m * 72cm)/1.482A = 16

Comment: @HussamMj I think that's because there is no way to solve this problem without more information. Ask your teacher; it's likely they made a mistake writing the homework.

Comment: You can also be an object of a bad joke. Someone who knows that your knowledge isn't the highest possible but you are not going to stop attempting to solve it as long as you can still breathe has fooled you to think that this is a valid and important problem. Very wide range of N is possible depending on the undefined parameters. You have already tried numerous formulas which all have something which is not given,